# Convert .py/.pyw to .exe

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I want to create an `.exe` file from a `.py` or `.pyw` file.

How can I do this? (with [cx-freeze](/questions/tagged/cx-freeze))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Code the file which will convert

1. Download `cx_Freeze` (if you didn't do that) [here](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/).
2. Create a new `Python` file and paste the following code:

---

```
import os
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter.messagebox import *

tk = Tk()
tk.title(".py -> .exe")
tk.resizable(0, 0)

f = None # file chosen

def browse():
    global f, btn
    try:
        f = askopenfile().name # get the path of the chosen file
        btn["text"] = os.path.basename(f)
    except:
        f = None

def convert():
    global f, btn, ver, des
    OK = False
    try:
        dots = 0
        for x in ver.get():
            if x == ".":
                dots += 1
            else:
                x = int(x)
        if dots < 4:
            OK = True # check the number of dots in the version
    except:
        showwarning("","The version must be int.int.int... with max 3 dots.")
    if OK:
        try:
            if f is None:
                showwarning("","You must choose a file to convert.")
                btn.focus()
            elif ver.get() == "":
                showwarning("","You must enter a version.")
                ver.focus()
            else:
                # create and fill the launch files
                with open("setup.py", "w") as f_:
                    f_.write("NAME = '" + f +
                        "'\nVERSION = '" + ver.get() +
                        "'\nDESCRIPTION = \"\"\"" + des.get(1.0, "end") +
                        "\"\"\"\n\nfrom cx_Freeze import setup, Executable\nsetup(name = NAME, version = VERSION, description = DESCRIPTION, executables = [Executable(NAME)])")
                with open("start.bat", "w") as f_:
                    f_.write("py setup.py build")
                os.system("start.bat") # run the launch file

                os.remove("setup.py")  # remove the created files
                os.remove("start.bat") #
                showinfo("Information","End. Your exe file is in folder 'build'.")
        except:
            showerror("Error","Unknown error detected.") # any unknown error

# GUI
Label(text="File to convert").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="w")
btn = Button(text="Browse...", command=browse)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
Label(text="Version").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="w")
ver = Entry(width=23)
ver.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=5)
ver.insert(0, "1.0")
Label(text="Description").grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="w")
des = ScrolledText(width=15, height=5, wrap=WORD)
des.grid(column=1, row=3)
Label(text="Convert to .exe").grid(column=0, row=4, sticky="w")
Button(text="Convert", command=convert).grid(column=1, row=4, pady=5)

tk.mainloop()
```

3. Run the code. Choose a file. Click the `convert` button.
4. A command prompt window allows you to see the progress.

---

#### Errors

1. **The command prompt stayed open a very short time**

- Change

  ```
    with open("start.bat", "w") as f_:
        f_.write("py setup.py build")
  ```

  by

  ```
    with open("start.bat", "w") as f_:
        f_.write("py setup.py build")
        f_.write("pause")
  ```

  Then, search the error on the Internet.
- Check if you have selected a `.py` or `.pyw` file.

2. **The folder "build" isn't created**

- check the path of the file to convert: does it contains accentuated characters , some spaces ? >> put the file for example on your desktop, or in a flash drive to avoid it.
- check the description: does it contains accentuated characters? Remove them.
- Have you installed `cx_Freeze`?

3. **You can't open your `.exe` file**

- If your code needs others files, like images, musics, then copy them in the current folder.
- Have you  checked your file? Does it contains some errors?
- If you use `tkinter`: have you looped the window?