# I am having a hard time turning my .py file into an executable file

Tags: python, installation, pygame, executable

So I just made my first game using pygame. I guess it should also be noted im working with ios on a mac

I downloaded PyInstaller, and when I use PyInstaller I get a file that gets the below messages in picture 1 when I try to execute it.
*The file's encoding is invalid for Python 3.x. IDLE will convert it to UTF-8. What is the current encoding*

[image]

I don't know what to fill in the blank instead of UTF-8 (whatever that means) so I just press ok and I get the below message in picture 2.

[image]

So when I want to turn the .py file into an executable file and it just turns it into a .pyc file that needs to be decoded. (whatever that means)

I used pycharm to write the code and when I put it into the pyinstaller it looks picture 3:

[image]

Anyways thanks for the help!

I've tried the pyinstaller --onefile -w [filename] but that doesnt work either

[image]

below is the code after I execute pyinstaller this what I get maybe this can help.

```
$ pyinstaller /Users/colemanschnaak/PycharmProjects/flappybird/flappybird.py 
282 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
282 INFO: Python: 3.7.7
299 INFO: Platform: Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
301 INFO: wrote /Users/colemanschnaak/flappybird.spec
305 INFO: UPX is not available.
306 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/colemanschnaak/PycharmProjects/flappybird', '/Users/colemanschnaak']
352 INFO: checking Analysis
359 INFO: Building because inputs changed
359 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
362 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
381 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2778 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
2782 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7'
4452 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4564 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4582 INFO: Analyzing /Users/colemanschnaak/PycharmProjects/flappybird/flappybird.py
4984 INFO: Processing module hooks...
4985 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
5203 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-win32com.py'.
5603 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
5605 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
5606 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
5607 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
5610 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
5695 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygame.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
5697 WARNING: Hidden import "pygame._view" not found!
5698 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
5712 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
5978 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
5997 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
6011 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
6015 INFO: Including run-time hook '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
6024 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
6762 INFO: Looking for eggs
6763 INFO: Using Python library /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
6770 INFO: Warnings written to /Users/colemanschnaak/build/flappybird/warn-flappybird.txt
6806 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /Users/colemanschnaak/build/flappybird/xref-flappybird.html
6821 INFO: checking PYZ
6824 INFO: Building because toc changed
6824 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/colemanschnaak/build/flappybird/PYZ-00.pyz
7273 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/colemanschnaak/build/flappybird/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
7280 INFO: checking PKG
7281 INFO: Building because toc changed
7282 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
7298 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
7299 INFO: Bootloader /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/run
7299 INFO: checking EXE
7301 INFO: Building because toc changed
7302 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
7302 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /Users/colemanschnaak/build/flappybird/flappybird
7308 INFO: Fixing EXE for code signing /Users/colemanschnaak/build/flappybird/flappybird
7313 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
7315 INFO: checking COLLECT
7315 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
WARNING: The output directory "/Users/colemanschnaak/dist/flappybird" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)
```

Then after I hit yes I get this:

```
WARNING: The output directory "/Users/colemanschnaak/dist/flappybird" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)y
On your own risk, you can use the option `--noconfirm` to get rid of this question.
312239 INFO: Removing dir /Users/colemanschnaak/dist/flappybird
312266 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
314548 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

if I hit no:

```
WARNING: The output directory "/Users/colemanschnaak/dist/flappybird" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)n
User aborted
```

also the default version of python on my mac is 2.7

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

will that have anything to do with why I cant package the .py file? sense I wrote it in 3.7

Comment: Please tell how are you using pyinstaller, Because When you try command **pyinstaller PyFilePath.py** it creates some folders in Pyfile directory

Comment: ok i just added a 3rd picture i hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think pyinstaller is not able to comprehend the path of the flapybird.py. You can try one thing, Copy the whole flapybird directory to the (python root) python37\libs\site-packeges\pyinstaller\ where pyinstaller.exe lies and then open bash with that directory and try **pyinstaller -w -f "flapybird\flapybird.py"** command.

Comment: Thanks! but still now luck :(

Comment: sorry ment to say no luck haha

Answer (score 0):

If you write the code in python 3, you can put some accentuated characters. But the Python 2 IDLE can’t read those characters.

PS : I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406974/converting-py-to-exe-using-cx-freeze) a GUI which converts a `.py` or `.pyw` file into a `.exe` file.

Comment: yeah, I tried using the GUI but for some reason when i put the .py file in it there wasnt a convert button, the only button was the browse button

Comment: Did you receive an error ? Were all the widgets present, or just the button? I don't know why it didn't work. With me the program works, either from the Python IDLE or by reading the file directly from the explorer.  But maybe you use Pycharm, Visual Studio or a debugger... In this case I can’t help you.

Comment: yeah I use pycharm :/ but just the one button to upload the file was present

Comment: ... I don’t understand.